# attributes for an angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which takes in an attribute of "attachmentType".

```
<attachment attachment-type="CK" />
```

How can I include another attribute (attachmentId) that gets another value from my page **together** with the above attribute (basically multiple attributes)?

For instance, below would be another separate attribute,

```
<attachment attachment-id={{cdmCtrl.copiedRow.CheckDepositHeaderId}} />
```

I tried something like the following, but syntactically, wasn't correct.

```
<attachment attachment-type="CK",  attachment-id={{cdmCtrl.copiedRow.CheckDepositHeaderId}} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wanted to pass dynamic value to directive by scope, you need to add that attribute inside `isolated scope` option of directive with `@`(one way binding) . You don't need to specify `,` between two attributes. They will be treated as independent attribute by default.

```
scope: {
   attachmentId: '@'
}
```

Inside directive link function/ controller you will get this `attachmentId` by `scope.attachmentId`. Also make sure to close out directive element, as its a custom element.

```
<attachment attachment-type="CK" 
   attachment-id={{cdmCtrl.copiedRow.CheckDepositHeaderId}}>
</attachment>
```